# How can I run basic EmberJS tutorial code by itself?

Tags: ember.js

I am going through this [EmberJS tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0). It gives you a basic overview of building an Ember application, and then gets into more specific basics. Starting at section 3 ("The Object Model"), it gives a lot of examples of writing code using Ember objects, but no straightforward instructions on how to run the basic examples. I would like to be able to run the code samples that they provide as I go along, so I can make changes / alterations and ideally gain a better understanding. I find that to be much better for retention than just reading over lots of samples.

There's a section on unit testing much deeper in the tutorial, but I'm at the very beginning [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/) working with basic objects.

Is there a straightforward way that I could run a .js file by itself containing, for example:

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    init() {
        var name = this.get('name');
        alert(`${name}, saying hello`);
    },

    say(thing) {
        var name = this.get('name');
        alert(`${name} says ${thing}`);
    }
});

let me = Person.create({
    name: 'My Name'
});

me.say('Hello');
```

...without needing a strong understanding of Ember architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this is a bit hacky, but it's the fastest way for you to get going to try some of those examples out.

Have a look at [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/fdfee361d6c07a29096d81ebcb86a5e4?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) twiddle. And you'll see I just included the code in the controller file.

You create a file in the demo folder, and include it somewhere and just play around with it.

```
// demo/person.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export const Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    init() {
        var name = this.get('name');
        alert(`${name}, saying hello`);
    },

    say(thing) {
        var name = this.get('name');
        alert(`${name} says ${thing}`);
    }
});

// controllers/application
import Ember from 'ember';

import { Person } from '../demo/person'

let me = Person.create({
    name: 'My Name'
});

me.say('Hello');

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It's fine that it's hacky, I'll figure out the "right" way to run / test the code later in the tutorial, but for the very early stages it didn't feel good not being able to run / test basic code from their examples.

Comment: @UpQuark You shouldn't skip steps in the learning process, naming conventions and structure are very important in ember